# Can a javascript variable be made local to a specific html element?

Tags: javascript, onclicklistener

As a novice Javascript programmer, I'd like to create an html document presenting a feature very similar to the "reveal spoiler" used extensively in the Stack Exchange  sites.

My document therefore has a few `<div>` elements, each of which has an `onClick` event listner which, when clicked,  should reveal a hiddent text.

I already know that this can be accomplished, e.g., by

`<div onclick="this.innerHTML='Revealed text'"> Click to reveal </div>`

However, I would like the text to be revealed to be initially stored in a variable, say `txt`, which will be used when the element is clicked, as in:

`<div onclick="this.innerHTML=txt"> Click to reveal </div>`

Since there will be many such `<div>` elements, I certainly cannot store the text to be revealed in a global variable.  My question is then:

Can I declare a variable  that is local to a specific html element?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can. HTML elements are essentially just Javascript Objects with properties/keys and values. So you could add a key and a value to an HTML element object.

But you have to add it to the `dataset` object that sits inside the element, like this:

```
element.dataset.txt = 'This is a value' // Just like a JS object
```

A working example of what you want could look like this:

```js
function addVariable() {
  const myElement = document.querySelector('div')
  myElement.dataset.txt = 'This is the extended data'
}

function showExtendedText(event) {
  const currentElement = event.currentTarget
  currentElement.innerHTML += currentElement.dataset.txt
}

addVariable() // Calling this one immediately to add variables on initial load
```

```html
<div onclick="showExtendedText(event)">Click to see more </div>
```

Or you could do it by adding the variable as a `data-txt` attribute right onto the element itself, in which case you don't even need the `addVariable()` function:

```js
function showExtendedText(event) {
  const currentElement = event.currentTarget
  currentElement.innerHTML += currentElement.dataset.txt
}
```

```html
<div onclick="showExtendedText(event)" data-txt="This is the extended data">Click to see more </div>
```

To access the data/variable for the specific element that you clicked on, you have to pass the `event` object as a function paramater. This `event` object is given to you automatically by the click event (or any other event).

Comment: "... essentially splitting the function above into two".  Yes, this is exactly what I'd like to do.  However, the first part will not run as a consequence of a click event, so I do not know how to acess the element I am buliding, as in 

`<div onclick="ShowVariable(event)">`

`<script>`

`SOME_UNKNOWN_WAY_TO_ACCESS_THIS_ELEMENT.dataset.txt = "This is the extended data"`

`</script>`

`</div>`

Comment: Oh I see what you mean @Ruy . It's just because you need to put the `element.dataset.txt = 'This is the extended data'` inside of a function called `ShowVariable(event)`. Then is should work. Whatever the name of the function is that happens "onclick" should be the exact same name of the function that holds the `element.dataset.txt = 'This is the extended data'` part. If you write it as a function and pass through the `event` object as a parameter, then you can access the currently clicked on `<div>` element with `event.currentTarget`. Here is an example https://jsfiddle.net/12scnzLu/7/

Answer (score 3):

Elements have attributes, so you can put the information into an attribute. Custom attributes should usually be [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes). On click, check if a parent element has one of the attributes you're interested in, and if so, toggle that parent.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const parent = e.target.closest('[data-spoiler]');
  if (!parent) return;
  const currentMarkup = parent.innerHTML;
  parent.innerHTML = parent.dataset.spoiler;
  parent.dataset.spoiler = currentMarkup;
});
```

```html
<div data-spoiler="foo">text 1</div>
<div data-spoiler="bar">text 2</div>
```

That's the closest you'll get to "a variable that is local to a specific html element". To define the text completely in the JavaScript instead, one option is to use an array, then look up the clicked index of the spoiler element in the array.

```js
const spoilerTexts = ['foo', 'bar'];
const spoilerTags = [...document.querySelectorAll('.spoiler')];

document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const parent = e.target.closest('.spoiler');
  if (!parent) return;
  const currentMarkup = parent.innerHTML;
  const index = spoilerTags.indexOf(parent);
  parent.innerHTML = spoilerTexts[index];
  spoilerTexts[index] = currentMarkup;
});
```

```html
<div class="spoiler">text 1</div>
<div class="spoiler">text 2</div>
```

There are also libraries that allow for that sort of thing, by associating each element with a *component* (a JavaScript function/object used by the library) and somehow sending a variable to that component.

```js
// for example, with React

const SpoilerElement = ({ originalText, spoilerText }) => {
  const [spoilerShown, setSpoilerShown] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <div onClick={() => setSpoilerShown(!spoilerShown)}>
      { spoilerShown ? spoilerText : originalText }
    </div>
  );
};
const App = () => (
  <div>
    <SpoilerElement originalText="text 1" spoilerText="foo" />
    <SpoilerElement originalText="text 2" spoilerText="bar" />
  </div>
)

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('.react')).render(<App />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for your answers, which helped immensely!  However, as a minimalist, I took all that I learned from you and came up with what I believe is the simplest possible code achieving my goal:

```html
<div spoiler = "foo" onclick="this.innerHTML=this.getAttribute('spoiler')">
  Click for spoiler
  </div>

<div spoiler = "bar" onclick="this.innerHTML=this.getAttribute('spoiler')">
  Click for spoiler
  </div>
```

Comment: Adding custom attributes to HTML elements except for when using `data-` prefix can break strict HTML validations. That's why the other answers suggested to use it, because it is an officially supported way to have attributes with custom names, and the access to their values is very straightforward, too.